# Adding a Task in outlook 2013 using Asp.net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, outlook

I have a asp.net Web App thru which i want to access Outlook 2013 and  add/edit/delete outlook tasks.

I also have Exchange Server 2010.

I just do not know how to proceed with the solution. Do i need to use JavaScript API for Office OR EWS OR what...

Pls suggest...

Answer (score 1):

For starters you can't access Outlook directly from a server/web application:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757

You also cannot use the JavaScript API for Office as there is currently no support for task items.

Your only option is to use Exchange Web Services.  Here's a good starting point:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj900166(v=exchg.150).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to do this, so this is very general advice.

I would suggest reading up on `EWS` first, and then looking at the `Javascript API for Office` after that, if there are compelling reasons why `EWS` won't work in your scenario.

After that, the next question you need to answer is whether you want the server to do the communication with Exchange, or the client.

The server (the "code behind") might be a better choice if you need to incorporate data from other sources than user input (such as a database) into the user tasks, or vice versa.

If you are going to do this all via `javascript` on the client, then the Javascript API might also be an option, assuming the functionality is there.

Hope this helps.